# Sybase view query - hardcoded value works but variable fails

Tags: t-sql, sybase, ibatis

Does anyone know why this works in approx 1 sec:

```
select Q.USR_LOAD_NBR from QUAD0066..QTS_LOAD_INFO Q where Q.KY_TO_STP = 2142870
```

but this takes more than 10 secs (and up to 5 minutes):

```
declare @groupId int
set @groupId = 2142870
select Q.USR_LOAD_NBR from QUAD0066..QTS_LOAD_INFO Q where Q.KY_TO_STP = @groupId
```

I'm having the exact same problem with ibatis with this query, except ibatis is timing out in like 15 seconds and causing my code to fail. ( less than 1 sec hard-coded, time-out with int parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the value hardcoded the query optimizer can select the best plan possible.
That does not happen when the value is a variable since the query optimizer doesn't know what the value might be.

Now what you can do is create a index for the `KY_TO_STP` column, prolly you be a nonclustered:

```
create nonclustered index on QTS_LOAD_INFO(KY_TO_STP)
```

You can add `unique` if you want every value in `KY_TO_STP` to be unique and you can replace `nonclustered` by `clustered` if `KY_TO_STP` is a primary key or if you can uniquelly identify each row with it (but don't forget that you can only have one clustered index per table).

Comment: That makes sense... I thought a textual substitution was occuring, but you are saying that the query is sending variables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got an error?
Did you run this code using different programs (for example ase isql and interactive sql)?

Comment: I'm using qwerybuilder.  I'm also using ibatis in a c# project.

Comment: Try run it using interactive sql (it's in sybase central). You will be sure the code is correct. Maybe is problem with formatting: more then one space or incorrect end of line. I sometimes had a problem with enter, without enter worked correctly. I don't know ibatis , so I can't help you with it.

Comment: @ParadoX what you stated is not a solution, it should be on comments.

Comment: Yes, I know. I hadn't option "add comment".